Why does my Javascript toggle two elements simultaneously?
I have two hidden DIVs on my page with buttons to toggle them when needed. One is the navigation menu and the other is a log-in form. I've used JQuery to toggle a nice slide down and up. I've now added some JavaScript to toggle the slide out when a user clicks on their respective buttons a second time or if they click outside of the revealed DIV.
Problem is, my JavaScript toggles both DIVs to appear and disappear together, regardless of which button you press!
    $('html').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == '#nav_btn') {
    $("#navigation").slideToggle("slow");
    } else {
    $("#navigation").slideToggle("slow");
    }
});

$('html').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == '#log_btn') {
    $("#loginDIV").slideToggle("slow");
    } else {
    $("#loginDIV").slideToggle("slow");
    }
});

It's no doubt something really obvious but what am I doing wrong?!

The code in the if and the else blocks are the same and you target the html element so anywhere you click will toggle both divs.

e.target.id shouldn't have "#", it should be if (e.target.id == 'nav_btn') .  And you're using slideToggle in both if and else which is so confusing

Thank you both. I've amended the targets from html to #nav_btn and #log_btn respectively (that was a schoolboy error) and removed the # from both e.target.id statements. Now the menus scroll down independently on the first click of their respective buttons and scroll up upon a second click, but I've lost the functionality to scroll them up when clicking elsewhere. It's close but not quite there!
